# UITableView not responding to selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I added to a `UIView` inside the main view. The table loads a custom cell and loads the data and responds to scrolling properly, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not being called. If I move the table outside its container `UIView`, the `delegate` method gets called.

So it only doesn't work when inside the container view, but that view has `userInteractionEnable = YES` and the table responds to scrolling.
The table is also set to single selection.

Any idea why it won't respond to selection?
Thanks in advance for any help

Here is some code:

```
self.table.delegate = self;
self.table.dataSource = self;


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.classNames count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ClassCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.tvCell;
        self.tvCell = nil;
    }

    //Set up custom cell

    return cell;
}

//When cell is tapped
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.classNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if([[AppManager sharedManager] isPad])
    {
        ClassWork *controller = [[ClassWork alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassWork_iPad" bundle:nil];
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        controller.delegate = self;
        [controller setClassIndex:indexPath.row];
        [controller setClassTitle:[NSString stringWithString:className]];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }

    else
    {
        if([[AppManager sharedManager] is4inchScreen])
        {
            ClassWork *controller = [[ClassWork alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassWork_iPhone4in" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            controller.delegate = self;
            [controller setClassIndex:indexPath.row];
            [controller setClassTitle:[NSString stringWithString:className]];
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }

        else
        {
            ClassWork *controller = [[ClassWork alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassWork_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            controller.delegate = self;
            [controller setClassIndex:indexPath.row];
            [controller setClassTitle:[NSString stringWithString:className]];
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

//Delete Cell
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.classNames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.classDays removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.classTimes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        //Get Corresponding File Path
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:(0)];
        NSString *classNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class%d", indexPath.row];
        NSString *classFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:classNum];

        //Remove Folder
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: classFolder error: nil];


        //Change numClasses
        NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:kNumClasses];

        //Get current number
        NSString *str = [[AppManager sharedManager] loadFileData:fileName];
        int numClasses = [str intValue] - 1;

        //Decrease by 1
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numClasses];

        //Re-write
        NSData *outFileData = [str dataUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];
        [[AppManager sharedManager] writeFileData:fileName :outFileData];


        //Rename class folders
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *newFilePath;
        NSString *newClassNum;
        int newIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < (numClasses + 1); i++)
        {
            classNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class%d", i];
            classFolder = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:classNum];

            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:classFolder])
            {
                newClassNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Class%d", newIndex];
                newFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:newClassNum];
                newIndex++;

                if(classFolder != newFilePath)
                {
                    // Rename the file by moving the file
                    [fileMgr moveItemAtPath:classFolder toPath:newFilePath error:nil];
                }
            }
        }

        //Reload Table
        [self.table reloadData];

        [self setNumberOfAssignmentsToCome];


        if(numClasses == 0)
        {
            self.noClassesLabel1.hidden = NO;
            self.noClassesLabel2.hidden = NO;
            self.table.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show some code please ?

Comment: Are you sure that the delegate and datasource is set to the files owner of UIViewController,

Comment: @AssadUllah I added code. It all works perfectly fine when I move the table outside the UIView it is in, but it doesn't work when it is inside the UIView

Comment: Do you use xibs or storyboards?

Comment: Sounds like there might be a conflicting UITapGestureRecognizer or something on the parent view... do you have anything that might be interfering like that?

Answer (score 18):

Turns out that there was a gesture recognizer sucking up all the touches. I changed it to be there at certain times and to be gone others, and now the table view is working properly

Comment: Thanks @jonathan. Gestures recogniser was the culprit in my case.